# Retrieve the related objects in MongoDB without a localField

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I use MongoDB to store Call Detail Records, which consist of A-legs and B-legs.

They are related as follows:

- All records (A & B-legs) are in the same `cdr` collection
- A-legs have a field `leg_type` that equals to `a`, B-legs have `b` of course
- B-legs have a field `a_leg` to indicate to what A-leg they belong.

At the moment we retrieve the A-legs we want, then loop through them and for every A-leg we retrieve the related B-legs (can be multiple), so all on the clientside.

I was wondering if I could do that in one query, and apparently you can with [$lookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). However it seems to be required that you can reference a field on the A-leg in this case, which would be an array of B-legs.
But I don't have that field, and before I spend unnecessary time to have such a field I was wondering if I could do it differently.

For completeness, this is how we retrieve the CDR's now:

```
    a_legs = mongo_db['cdr'] \
        .find({'group_id': group.id, 'leg_type': 'a'}) \
        .sort('times.created', pymongo.DESCENDING) \
        .limit(50)

    for cdr in a_legs:
        # Find B-legs
        cdr['b_legs'] = mongo_db['cdr'] \
            .find({'a_leg': cdr['call_id'], 'leg_type': 'b'}) \
            .sort('times.created', pymongo.ASCENDING)
```

So the bottomline question: can we do the above in a single query to MongoDB?

I tried doing it like this:

```
db.cdr.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "cdr",
        localField: "call_id",
        foreignField: "a_leg",
        as: "b_legs"
    }
}])
```

But it shows me no results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help of Studio3T which helped me about to construct the query step by step. This is what I ended up with:

```
mongo_db['cdr'].aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "group_id" : 585, 
                "leg_type" : "a"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "cdr", 
                "let" : {
                    "call_id" : "$call_id"
                }, 
                "pipeline" : [
                    {
                        "$match" : {
                            "$expr" : {
                                "$and" : [
                                    {
                                        "$eq" : [
                                            "$leg_type", 
                                            "b"
                                        ]
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "$eq" : [
                                            "$a_leg", 
                                            "$$call_id"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$project" : {
                            "_id" : False, 
                            "raw" : False, 
                            "leg_type" : False
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "$sort" : {
                            "times.created" : 1
                        }
                    }
                ], 
                "as" : "b_legs"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : False, 
                "raw" : False, 
                "leg_type" : False
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : False
    }
);
```

I needed to use $lookup together with `pipeline`. I also had to create an index ofcourse on `call_id` to make it work fast.